# Reason for using smart pointers with a container

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, smart-pointers

Simply written I would like to ask "what is a good reason to use smart pointers?" 
 for ex `std::unique_ptr`

However, I am not asking for reasons to use smart pointers *over regular (dumb) pointers*. I think every body knows that or a quick search can find the reason.

What I am asking is a comparison of these two cases:

Given a class (or a struct) named `MyObject` use

1. `std:queue<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>>queue;`

rather than

2. `std:queue<MyObject> queue;`

(it can be any container, not necessarily a queue)

Why should someone use option 1 rather than 2?

Comment: 1. To be able to store classes *derived from* `MyObject`. 2. As an alternative to `std::optional<MyObject>`. 3. To be able to store non-movable (and non-copyable) classes.

Comment: The main reason for smart pointers (IMO) is *ownership*. Who is "owning" a resource? Can that ownership be shared (`std::shared_pointer`) or not (`std::unique_ptr`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `std:queue<MyObject>` also defines ownership.

Comment: The simpler way to phrase this question is: When to use dynamic storage?

Answer (score 7):

That is actually a good question.

There are a few reasons I can think of:

- Polymorphism works only with references and pointers, not with value types. So if you want to hold derived objects in a container you can't have `std::queue<MyObject>`. One options is `unique_ptr`, another is `reference_wrapper`
- the contained objects are referenced (*) from outside of the container. Depending on the container, the elements it holds can *move*, invalidating previous references to it. For instance `std::vector::insert` or the move of the container itself. In this case `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>` assures that the reference is valid, regardless of what the container does with it (ofc, as long as the `unique_ptr` is alive).
  In the following example in `Objects` you can add a bunch of objects in a queue. However two of those objects can be special and you can access those two at any time.

  ```
  struct MyObject { MyObject(int); };

  struct Objects
  {
      std::queue<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> all_objects_;

      MyObject* special_object_ = nullptr;
      MyObject* secondary_special_object_ = nullptr;

      void AddObject(int i)
      {
          all_objects_.emplace(std::make_unique<MyObject>(i));
      }

      void AddSpecialObject(int i)
      {
          auto& emplaced = all_objects_.emplace(std::make_unique<MyObject>(i));
          special_object_ = emplaced.get();
      }

      void AddSecondarySpecialObject(int i)
      {
          auto& emplaced = all_objects_.emplace(std::make_unique<MyObject>(i));
          secondary_special_object_ = emplaced.get();
      }
  };
  ```

(*) I use "reference" here with its english meaning, not the C++ type. Any way to refer to an object (e.g. via a raw pointer)

Comment: So what you are saying is either when I want to hold derived objects or when I create the objects outside of the container and just put them inside?

Comment: if you create an object outside and put it into the container you don't need a `unique_ptr` for that. You need a `unique_ptr` if you for hold a raw pointer to an element from the container.

Comment: @KansaiRobot I've added an example into the answer.

Comment: More generally: `MyObject` might be non-movable and non-copyable (or just too expensive to). `std::deque` and `std::vector` require this (and so do adaptors of these types like `std::queue`).

Answer (score 0):

Usecase: You want to store something in a `std::vector` with constant indices, while at the same time being able to remove objects from that vector.

If you use pointers, you can delete a pointed to object and set `vector[i] = nullptr`, (and also check for it later) which is something you cannot do when storing objects themselves. If you'd store Objects you would have to keep the instance in the vector and use a flag `bool valid` or something, because if you'd delete an object from a vector all indices after that object's index change by -1.

---

Note: As mentioned in a comment to this answer, the same can be archieved using `std::optional`, if you have access to C++17 or later.

Comment: The described use case could also be achieved with `std::optional`, and optional would have the benefit that it is guaranteed that the value allocated as part of the optional, and has the benefit that it does not need an own allocation for each object to store.

Comment: @t.niese Yes you are right. I'm circumventing the allocation issue with boost's pool allocator though.

Answer (score -2):

The first declaration generates a container with pointer elements and the second one generates pure objects.

Here are some benefits of using pointers over objects:

1. They allow you to create dynamically sized data structures.
2. They allow you to manipulate memory directly (such as when packing or
   unpacking data from hardware devices.)
3. They allow object references(function or data objects)
4. They allow you to manipulate an object(through an API) without needing to know the details of the object(other than the API.)
5. (raw) pointers are usually well matched to CPU registers, which makes dereferencing a value via a pointer efficient. (C++ “smart” pointers are more complicated data objects.)

---

Also, polymorphism is considered as one of the important features of Object-Oriented Programming.
In C++ polymorphism is mainly divided into two types:

- Compile-time Polymorphism

This type of polymorphism is achieved by function overloading or operator overloading.

- Runtime Polymorphism

This type of polymorphism is achieved by Function Overriding which if we want to use the base class to use these functions, it is necessary to use pointers instead of objects.

Comment: The question is about using pointers in containers, not the possible advantages of using pointers in general.

Comment: I disagree with most of the points here. 1 most of the containers already allocate memory dynamically, another level of indirection is not a good thing. 2. You can't do that with smart pointers. 3. I don't understand. 4. That is true for the value objects also 5. `unique_ptr` with default deleter is a 0 cost abstraction, it adds absolutely no overhead over raw pointers.